# Creating a SignalR "Lobby"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm currently in the process of making a multiplayer quiz, and I've stumbled upon a problem.

After a user clicks on a category name such as "Geography", I want that player to be in a "lobby" of some kind, where he is waiting for a second player to join.

When the second player joins, I want them to go to the next page where the questions are.

How is this achieved using SignalR? I've read that you can use Groups for this, but most people say that you shouldn't control which groups the different clients join..

Comment: "but most people say that you shouldn't control which groups the different clients join" That's utter tosh the foundation for SignalR was for groups and "sending messages to groups" - All what you are asking is achievable and not that complicated... note that SignalR is just a layer on top... Continue to build as is - moving between rooms and adding the user to a group. To Identify "x" users in a room, Count the SignalR connections - If you've mapped users to a connection, this is fairly easy.

Comment: Well your explanation was just great man, thanks.

Comment: Currently working at the min, I'll elaborate as soon as poss.

Comment: Haha allright man